# Spring how create filter that reads body but keeps request intact

Tags: spring, spring-boot

First i read the answer here: [How to get request body params in spring filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790323/how-to-get-request-body-params-in-spring-filter)

But using ContentCachingRequestWrapper is not working:

I need to calculate a value for every request body (soap requests) for this i created a filter (extending OncePerRequestFilter):

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddHashFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final RequestHash hash;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest requestToUse = request;
        if(!(request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper)){
            requestToUse = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        }

        hash.hash(IOUtils.toString(requestToUse.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this somehow destroys the request - i get 400. What i tried:

- using `request.geReader` -> get an exception that getReader was already called
- omit using `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` -> no change

i also tried this variant to read the body (from examples i found)

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddHashFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final RequestHash hash;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        hash.hash(new String(StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(request.getInputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is same: all request are quit with 400.

But if i remove the actual work/ use of this filter (only keeping `filterChain.doFilter...`) it is working.

So how can i read complete body and keep it usable for everything after?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP request could be read **only once**, so if you read it in filter you cannot use it again.

Spring provides its own class that extends `HttpServletRequest` and allows reading its contents multiple times. And that resolves your problem. See this question and my answer to it:

- [How to get request body params in Spring filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790323/how-to-get-request-body-params-in-spring-filter/65791269#65791269)

Comment: as i wrote, using the ContentCachingRequestWrapper does not help. but i will check the examples again..